# Why segment fault occurs when redirect outstream to a file?

Tags: c++

The following code runs OK, but when line 9 `cout.rdbuf(x);` is removed , segment fault occurs.
Would everyone tell me the reason? 
I'm not familiar with C++...
But I must cout continually after the outstream directing to out.txt.
My environment is Ubuntu 12.
Thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    ofstream outf("out.txt");
    streambuf* x = cout.rdbuf(outf.rdbuf());// redirect to out.txt
    cout << "Testn"<<endl;  // write to out.txt
    cout.rdbuf(x);  // recovery
    cout << "Test2n"<<endl; // write to screen
    return 0;
}
```

Segment fault occurs in code below, though all content is printed to out.txt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    ofstream outf("out.txt");
    streambuf* x = cout.rdbuf(outf.rdbuf());// redirect to out.txt
    cout << "Testn"<<endl;  // write to out.txt
//    cout.rdbuf(x);        // recovery
    cout << "Test2n"<<endl;     
    cout << "Test3n"<<endl; 
    cout << "Test4n"<<endl; 
    cout << "Test5n"<<endl; 
    //Test2n~Test5n is printed to out.txt, but segment fault occurs now.    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused (as you've identified) by allowing the two output streams to be closed while they both share a single buffer.  We can see this by compiling the code and running it in Valgrind:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall -Wextra 52079058.cpp -o 52079058
$ valgrind -q --leak-check=full ./52079058
==27111== Invalid read of size 8
==27111==    at 0x4985EC8: pubsync (streambuf:278)
==27111==    by 0x4985EC8: std::ostream::flush() (ostream.tcc:219)
==27111==    by 0x491C0EB: std::ios_base::Init::~Init() (ios_init.cc:134)
==27111==    by 0x4BE28F0: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:108)
==27111==    by 0x4BE29E9: exit (exit.c:139)
==27111==    by 0x4BCCB1D: (below main) (libc-start.c:344)
```

Here, we can see that one stream is trying to flush to the buffer that the other stream has deleted.  Hence, we always need to ensure that each buffer is owned by exactly one stream before this point.

---

If you need to ensure that `std::cout` has its buffer restored regardless of code path, you might want to create a scope-based guard object that will restore it when it's destructed.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class stream_redirection
{
    std::ostream& from;
    std::ofstream to;
    std::streambuf *const saved;
public:
    stream_redirection(std::ostream& from, const std::string& filename)
        : from{from},
          to{filename},
          saved{from.rdbuf(to.rdbuf())}
    {}
    stream_redirection(const stream_redirection&) = delete;
    void operator=(const stream_redirection&) = delete;
    ~stream_redirection()
    {
        from.rdbuf(saved);
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        auto guard = stream_redirection(std::cout, "out.txt");

        std::cout << "Testn"<<std::endl;  // write to out.txt
        std::cout << "Test2n"<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "Test3n"<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Test4n"<<std::endl; // write to screen
    std::cout << "Test5n"<<std::endl;
}
```

If you create `guard` directly in `main()`, rather than in an inner scope as I've done here to demonstrate the switching, then the redirection will be cleaned up at program exit (i.e. when `main()` returns).

---

I'd argue that having to create such a class indicates a severe design flaw somewhere in your program.  Any subsystem that needs to produce output ought to be passed a stream on which to write that output (some would go further, and argue that logging and error streams should also be passed where needed, too).